# How to connect a mobile device using the cellular network to MS Azure

Tags: azure

Just after a bit of advice please.  We currently have a series of local access databases which reside on our field workers tablets.   Work is assigned to these field workers using our server side web application.  The workers then receive their work to their local tables using a code which sends and receives data to and from our internal domain server.

We are planning on moving away from our internal domain server to MS Azure.  In order to do this we would like to be able to route all the traffic from the mobile devices to a proxy and allow one address (the proxy) to connect to Azure as it will be near impossible to whitelist all IP's in use on the cellular network.

I was wondering if anyone could shed any light on the best way of achieving something like this please? How would a proxy be set up and how could be only route the traffic trying to access MS Azure via the proxy whilst maintaining normal traffic using a direct route?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tony

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, you would probably be in better shape to setup a VPN (Your security appliance or firewall should have one but if you want a dedicated one, look at [OpenVPN](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04)). Then you just have all the tablets connect to the VPN and then as far as Azure is concerned, you only need to whitelist the office. Windows and Android can both connect to a VPN out of the box.

Good luck on the migration.

Comment: It should be noted, there are easier ways to install OpenVPN than that, its just an example, I'd probably recommend ClearOS or something if you wanted an easy way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, just wondering is there an automatic way for our tablets to connect to the VPN without having to enter authentication details?  We would like the process to be automatic without having to rely on usernames/passwords etc.

Comment: If you're on windows tablets and you're using active directory, you could tie into that, otherwise you may need an app on the devices to facilitate an automatic connection.